# Can you search within a specific graph path (taggable_friends) in a Facebook Graph Request?

Tags: swift, facebook-graph-api

I have an action in my app that I'd ideally like to leverage the user's taggable friends for, but performing a Graph API request for the taggable friends' pictures takes far too long, even when requesting the smallest sized picture. Ideally, I'd present a list of only the names of the taggable friends, and then upon selection of a given name a second graph request would be performed to grab the name's associated picture.

Looking through Facebook's developer site, I found the topic of searching on [this page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api), but I don't think the User Taggable Friend node counts as a User type. Is there some way to search that path? I've tried a few different variations of

```
FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me/taggable_friends/search?q=NAME"...)
```

with no luck.

Comment: no, there is no such thing, i am afraid.

Comment: What made you think this would need any kind of "searching"? You already got the token-id corresponding to each single name you got from the taggable_friends endpoint, so what else do you need to specifically request a particular user's profile picture? Works the same way as with "regular" user profile pics, you just create an image element with the source pointing to `https://graph.facebook.com/{id-goes-here}/picture`, and the API will automatically redirect that to the correct CDN image URL ...

Comment: @CBroe that's something that's been puzzling to me, I have a pull to refresh set up and I noticed that each taggable_friend's ID changes whenever there's a new graph request. I can't find any developer documentation that talks about what exactly the taggable_friend ID _is_, since it doesn't seem to work like the user's ID.

Comment: It's not supposed to work like an id, you are not supposed to be able to identify these users inside your app until they decide to join it. That's also why those tokens are short-lived, and you might get different ones on the next request. Despite documentation, using token/picture does not seem to work; but `me/taggable_friends` returns a `picture` property already, and that includes a URL you can use to show the profile picture; you don't have to load it straight away.

Comment: @CBroe ahh gotcha, okay that's the perfect solution for me then! Thanks for the nudge in the right direction.